# transfer file from GCS bucket to SFTP server in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, sftp, jsch, google-cloud-storage

I am able to read files from GCS bucket, but all the libraries like **jsch** which does file transfer to SFTP server look for a file path, instead of the file in memory.
I don't want to write the file I read from GCS to a disk, How do I transfer the file in memory to SFTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to upload in-memory data. JSch actually has loads of `ChannelSftp.put` methods overloads that can upload in-memory data.

The basic one is [with use of `InputStream`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-):

```
public void put(InputStream src, String dst) throws SftpException
```

The other options is [with use of `OutputStream`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-):

```
public OutputStream put(String dst) throws SftpException
```